# Applied for a job that promised 40+ hours a week, but after being hired, I don't work that many hours. What is this called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I went for a job interview and got the job guaranteed 40+ hours a week but I’m not getting 40 hours a week and boss is saying he’s trying to find me hours but at the moment he can only offer me 25 approximately. What do you label that as?

I’ve read some old posts and people suggest lie : reneger : welcher … however I don’t think that quite fits in relation to this being an employment issue and no I haven’t signed a contract yet.

Comment: A promise is a promise, even if there's no contract. Those words all apply casually, but not legally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m not looking at this legally at all I just want to know what the terminology is for when someone says something yet doesn’t do it

Comment: In more than a few movies I've seen over the years, an hourly employee tells their boss that they "need more hours". But I don't recall hearing a name used for an employer who offers 40 hours but the reality is closer to 25, or recall hearing a word for the situation itself.  Absent anything written, the employer could always claim they said "*up to* 40 hours". Depending on your locale, it could be "hire/fire at will", that is, at the employer's sole discretion, and in such places there'd be very little or nothing the employee can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-word term in the domain of legal vocabulary, since it seems that such a term is what is wanted, nothing seems to exist; the three-word  term "*breach of contract*" appears to be right, but yet it is not  exact: in order to be precise you would have to say "*partial breach of contract*" ("partial breach" for short).

[Thesaurus.net](https://www.thesaurus.net/breach%20of%20contract)

> [partial breach of contract](https://aavenir.com/glossary/breach-of-contract/https://aavenir.com/glossary/breach-of-contract/)
>
> **Key Takeaways**
>
> •   A breach of contract occurs when one party in a binding agreement fails to deliver according to the terms of the agreement.
> •   A breach of contract can happen in both a written and an oral contract.
> •   The parties involved in a breach of contract may resolve the issue among themselves, or in a court of law.
> •   There are different types of contract breaches, including a minor or material breach and an actual or anticipatory breach.

Comment: I doubt she had a contract...

Comment: @Lambie She has no written contract since she signed nothing; however the reference mentions oral contracts.

Comment: This is indeed a breach of contract (regardless of whether it was oral or written) **if** we take at face value the OP's description of what happened: that she was **guaranteed** that number of hours. Whether the words uttered by the employer's agent actually amounted to a guarantee may, of course, be debatable, but that is outside the scope of the question.